# Extract email addresses of meeting attendees using Outlook command line

Tags: command-line, microsoft-outlook, meetings

Is there a way to extract email addresses of attendees of a meeting using Outlook command line?

Comment: What version are you even running?

Comment: Sorry, I am running outlook 2003 but I can upgrade to 2007